# Trying to write a loop that goes through my array and increments health of each player by 100

Tags: java, arrays, loops

> Print Screen:

```
Player13
Character Name: Fourz, Class Name: Ninja
Strength: 17, Agility: 21, Stamina: 17, Intellect: 25, Spirit: 20, Health: 52, Mana: 50
```

I just need a loop to go through my 16 different sets of player stats and give a health bonus of 100. Really struggling with writing a correct loop.

```
public static void sortPlayersByHealth() {

    for (int outer = 0; outer < playerObjectArray.length -1; outer ++) {

        for (int inner = 0; inner < playerObjectArray.length - 1; inner ++ ) {


            int num1 = playerObjectArray[inner].gethealth();
            //must + 1 for it to know to go to the next number and find the > number.
            int num2 = playerObjectArray[inner+1].gethealth();
            if(num1 > num2) {
                Player Player = playerObjectArray[inner];

                playerObjectArray[inner] = playerObjectArray[inner+1];
                playerObjectArray[inner+1] = Player; 
            }
```

This is a loop I previously wrote to help loop through all 16 player stats, sorting them by lowest to highest with their health score. Any help with changing this syntax to increment health by 100 is greatly appreciated.

Sorry if this is not making sense, I am new to programming, and new to stackoverflow.

Comment: "new to programming" - then I'd suggest some basic tutorials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementing a certain section of an array by 100?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603687/incrementing-a-certain-section-of-an-array-by-100). Just to be clear, this is much better than the dupe, but really should be an edit to that question (not a whole new question).

Comment: @MitchWheat I have gone over the basic tutorials, i'm currently studying this stuff but i'm just stuck and need some outside help.

Comment: how is your playerObjectArray declared like? Have you tried debugging your code to see how the values are changing?

Comment: @H-Patel my code is huge, because this is our first assigment...do ou mean this? playerObjectArray[0] = new Player ("Player1", "Drone", "Ninja", DroneNinja[0], DroneNinja[1], DroneNinja[2], DroneNinja[3], DroneNinja[4], DroneNinja[5], DroneNinja[6]);

Comment: @Mac sorry for the dupe, still just getting to know this.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void BumpHealth() {
  for (Player player : playerObjectArray) {
    player.health += 100;
  }
}
```

Assuming, of course, that the player object's health variable is called 'health'.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind exposing the health var public, the answer that says `player.health += 100` its obvious more efficient, otherwise:

Implement a

```
public void changeHealth(int value) {
    this.health += value;    //as value parameter is a signed integer if you pass negative value you can "remove" too
}
```

in the Player class. Assuming health is the name of the field.

Or using set and get methods

```
player.setHealth(player.getHealth() + 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is two separate operations.

1. Sort by Player Health
2. Increment Player Health by variable

I would advise checking out the following two things for the first option:

[Using Array.Sort](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-tip-how-to-sort-array-in-java-java-util-arrays/)
[Using Array.Sort for Comparator](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

A simple example plays out something like so:

```
Player[] myPlayerArray = new Player[2]; //get from whereever
Arrays.sort(myPlayerArray, new Comparator<Player>() {
    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        return p1.Health.compareTo(p2.Health); //or however you want it ordered
    }
});
```

You can also explore more complex options but that is all for now.

As for incrementing the health of each player you can implement a simple `for` or `foreach` loop to deal with that.

Like:

```
int increment = 100;
for (Player player : myPlayers) {
    player.Health += increment;
}
```

EDIT:

Added some links to help you with this:

- [Lessons: Algorithms - Sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/#sorting)
- [Array Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)
- [Array search and sort](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/arrays_search.htm)